# Why doesn't jQuery UI see jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, loading

I've built a JavaScript widget that must be embeddable on any third-party site, in any environment. The widget relies on jQuery and jQuery UI. I followed the steps in [How to embed Javascript widget that depends on jQuery into an unknown environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170439/how-to-embed-javascript-widget-that-depends-on-jquery-into-an-unknown-environment) to add jQuery in a responsible manner -- works great for embedding jQuery. But when I try to add jQuery UI, it fails. Here's the code:

```
(function(window, document, version, callback) {
  var j, d;
  var loaded = false;
  if (!(j = window.jQuery) || version > j.fn.jquery || callback(j, loaded)) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js";
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (!loaded && (!(d = this.readyState) || d == "loaded" || d == "complete")) {
            callback((j = window.jQuery).noConflict(1), loaded = true);
            j(script).remove();
        }
    };
    document.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(script)
  }
})(window, document, "1.3.2", function($, jquery_loaded) {
    $.getScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.js', function(){
      console.log('loaded');
    });
});
```

When I run this, I get the 'loaded' mesage, followed by an error saying that "$ is undefined" on line 15 of jquery-ui.js. But how can $ be undefined when I'm using $.getScript() to load jQuery UI? And why do I see the message 'loaded' before I get the error? According to the jQuery documentation, getScript shouldn't execute the callback until the script has been loaded and executed.

Is there any way I can use this framework to include jQuery UI, or do I need to use a script loader like RequireJS in order to load everything, enforce dependencies, etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By calling `.noConflict(1)`, the same as `.noConflict(true)`, you're deleting jQuery, just remove the `1`.  The `true` argument to [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) tells jQuery to remove not only `$`, but `window.jQuery`, which jQuery UI is trying to use afterwards, when *it* loads.

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6MxFN/), see there are no errors in the console.

Comment: bah! That was it. Loading nicely in FF / Chrome / Safari.