# Javascript access denied error on page partial load - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On **thirdpartydomain.com** I want to embed a simple `<script>` tag that pulls in a script from **mydomain.com/myscript.js**, which simply creates a little `<div>` and pulls partial page content from **mydomain.com/mypage.htm**.

Here's the script, adapted from: [How to embed Javascript widget that depends on jQuery into an unknown environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170439/how-to-embed-javascript-widget-that-depends-on-jquery-into-an-unknown-environment)

```
var myEmbedId = '12345';
var myEmbedContainerId = 'myEmbedContainer_' + myEmbedId;
document.write('<div id="' + myEmbedContainerId + '">IF ALL GOES WELL, THIS TEXT WILL BE REPLACED WITH MYPAGE.HTM CONTENTS');
document.write('</div>');

    (function (window, document, version, callback) {
        var j, d;
        var loaded = false;
        if (!(j = window.jQuery) || version > j.fn.jquery || callback(j, loaded)) {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src = "http://mydomain.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js";
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (!loaded && (!(d = this.readyState) || d == "loaded" || d == "complete")) {
                    callback((j = window.jQuery).noConflict(1), loaded = true);
                    j(script).remove();
                }
            };
            document.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(script)
        }
    })(window, document, "1.3", function ($, jquery_loaded) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('jquery loaded!');

            var myRefreshUrl = 'http://mydomain.com/mypage.htm';
            alert('refreshing from ' + myRefreshUrl);

            $.get(myRefreshUrl, function(data){ 
                var returnData = data;
                alert('return data: ' + data);
                $('#' + myEmbedContainerId).html(data); });

            alert('load complete v2');

        });
    });
```

In IE, I get an Access Denied error from Javascript; in Firefox I just get no data returned.

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create an AJAX request to a different domain from the one that is hosting the current window context.

To pull off what you're describing, you can do something like:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://mydomain.com/dynamic.js?data=somepage.htm';
someContainer.appendChild(script);
```

Within that `dynamic.js`, you can wrap the HTML contents in a `document.write()`. The net effect is the same as inserting the result of the AJAX request at the same point in the DOM.

Comment: Crossdomain is req'd, so document.write() is about to get a workout. Thanks