# embed a jquery script after jquery is loaded by widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6065421 was helpful to see how to confirm jquery has been loaded.
my widget will need a class that was written using jquery. may i have some assistance on embedding this other class built using jquery?
thank you,

below is the snippet from the above link with my code added in the final portion as noted in the code comments:

```
    (function(window, document, version, callback) {
    var j, d;
    var loaded = false;
    if (!(j = window.jQuery) || version > j.fn.jquery || callback(j, loaded)) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "/media/jquery.js";
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (!loaded && (!(d = this.readyState) || d == "loaded" || d == "complete")) {
                callback((j = window.jQuery).noConflict(1), loaded = true);
                j(script).remove();
            }
        };
        document.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(script)
    }
})(window, document, "1.3", function($, jquery_loaded) { //my code added below
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
script_tag.setAttribute("src", "http://mysite.com/widget/slides.jquery.js");
(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);

$('#slides').slides({}); //this line gives an error.
});
```

right now, i am trying the following based on the response(s) provided to this question (line that throws error is noted with a comment):

```
//this function is called after jquery being embedded has been confirmed. {mysite} placeholder is nonexistent in actual code.
function main() {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var css_link = $("<link>", {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        type: "text/css",
        href: "http://mysite/widget/widget.css"
    });
    css_link.appendTo('head');

    $('#crf_widget').after('<div id="crf_widget_container"></div>');

    /******* Load HTML *******/
    var jsonp_url = "http://mysite/widget.php?callback=?";
    $.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
        $('#crf_widget_container').html(data);

        $('#category_sel').change(function(){
            alert(this.value);
        });

        $.getScript("http://mysite/widget/slides.jquery.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            alert(1); //fires ok
            $('#slides').slides({}); //errors
        });
    });
});
}

error 1: $ is undefined .../slides.jquery.js?_=1341349267810 Line 22
error 2: $("#slides").slides is not a function .../widget.js?1341349266628 Line 61
```

$('#slides').slides({}); works when i tested the workings of the widget. however, when making it into a widget, the above errors are what i've faced.

anyone with more suggestions?

after waiting a couple weeks, i just took the code from the jquery class that i needed and put it inside the body after the jquery's load was confirmed. i would have preferred to import the jquery class after jquery was loaded, but i couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after waiting a couple weeks, i just took the code from the jquery class that i needed and put it inside the body after the jquery's load was confirmed. i would have preferred to import the jquery class after jquery was loaded, but i couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've already loaded jQuery, maybe it would be easier to use the [`$.getScript()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to get your `slides.jquery.js` file - something like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
(function(window, document, version, callback) {
    var j, d, loaded = false;
    if (!(j = window.jQuery) || version > j.fn.jquery || callback(j, loaded)) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "/media/jquery.js";
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (!loaded && (!(d = this.readyState) || d == "loaded" || d == "complete")) {
                callback((j = window.jQuery).noConflict(1), loaded = true);
                j(script).remove();
            }
        };
        document.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(script)
    }
})(window, document, "1.3", function($, jquery_loaded) { //my code added below
    // use $.getScript
    $.getScript("http://mysite.com/widget/slides.jquery.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        $('#slides').slides({});
    });
});
```

Comment: i've updated my initial question to show the current function i am using. it is using the approach you've suggested, but the line in the body is throwing error still. i have tested this line that throws the error with normal non-widget approach, and there's not a problem. so, it seems jquery is not available when needed. the code preceding the $.getScript block does not give a problem, which is jquery-supported syntax.

Comment: What error? Are you sure `$('#slides')` exists? Why is `$.getScript()` inside of a `$.getJSON()`, it should be outside of that function unless `$('#slides')` is inside of the HTML that is loaded. Have you heard about [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/)?

Comment: i've edited my question to show the errors. $.getScript() is nested in the getJSON() for the very reason you noted. i looked into yepnope.js, but i wonder is it possible to correct my current code setup since i didn't see a 'making-a-widget' example there?